# Fade-in and fade-out content simple slider?

Tags: jquery

I am not sure how to add on to this very very simple slider I am trying to build. Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2L46/)

**My slider function**

```
  function fadeContent() {

      $(".div-roles div:hidden:first-child").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500, function () {
          $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
          fadeContent();
      });

  }
```

If you know of a better way to write this, then please share, you can add onto my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2L46/)

I tried adding classes and animating stuff similar to a click function but it doesn't appear to work the same, I got the idea of this code elsewhere, and I have never passed the function name inside the function ex. `fadeContent();` so to me it looks like it's what causes it to loop, not 100% sure if it's that or the `.appendTo`.

So the actual question I have for this post would be to look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2L46/) and you see `.static-loader` it is set at 0%, I want to animate it to 100% inside the function, so as the content is fading in at `.fadeIn(500)` id like the css fading in the 100% at the same time I tried many different ways.

I am just not sure what angle to take, and am hoping to share some ideas with you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `fadeOut` in `fadeIn callback function` like,

```
function fadeContent() {
    $('.static-loader').animate({'width':'100%'},2000);
    $(".div-roles div:hidden:first-child").fadeIn(2500,function(){
       $('.static-loader').width('0%');
       $(this).fadeOut(2000, function () {
          $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
          fadeContent();           
       }); 
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2L46/2/)

Comment: Yeah this looks good, I can work with this, setting the time to be the same works well, I honestly didnt think of that I was trying to bind both inside the function.